# Softmax layer and last layer of neural net

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have doubt suppose last layer before softmax layer has 1000 nodes and I have only 10 classes to classify how does softmax layer which should output 1000 probability output only 10 probabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the 1000-node layer will be the input to the 10-node layer. Basically,

```
x_10 = w^T * y_1000
```

The `w` has to be of the size `1000 x 10`. Now, softmax function will be applied on `x_10` to produce the probability output for 10 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong in your understanding! The 1000 nodes, will output 10 probabilities for EACH example, the softmax is an ACTIVATION function! It will take the linear combination of the previous layer depending on the incoming and outgoing weights, and no matter what, output the number of probabilities equal to the number of class! If you an add more details, like maybe giving an example of what you're neural network looks like, we can help you further and explain in a lot more depth so you understand what's going on!